# Trying to edit results before displaying them on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following does not seem to be working properly.

```
    success: function(results) 
    { 
        var $results = $(results);

        $results.find('a[href$=".exe"]').each(function(){
            if (FileExists(this.href) == false) {
               $(this).parent().remove(); 
            } 
        }); 

        $("#divSearchResults").empty().append($results);
    }
```

It should be removing any .exe links from results then appending the modified results to screen.

EDIT 1: Here is the script for the FileExists function:

```
function FileExists(path) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    FileExist = fso.FileExists(path);

    if (FileExist == true) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: results contains something like this:

```
<div><a href="link1.xls">link 1</a></div>  
<div><a href="link2.exe">link 2</a></div>  
<div><a href="link3.doc">link 3</a></div>  
<div><a href="link4.aspx">link 4</a></div>
```

Comment: Is FileExists working correctly?

Comment: What happens? Is there an error message? What exactly does `results` contain? What is `FileExists`?

Comment: @PetersenDidIt: As far as I can tell, yet. If I manually enter a file location which exists, it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

Comment: @RoToRa:  I've updated the original question to show the FileExists function.

Comment: @RoToRa: It does not give any error messages. I've updated the original question to show an example of what results might contain.

Comment: These results, are they coming from the web? In that case you might be running into the same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy which would prevent you from extracting data from your users computers.

Comment: @Kristoffer S Hansen: The results are coming from our own internal intranet server, so I have full control over the results. In our network, all users have Internet Explorer... I have set their browsers to allow the intranet to have full access to their computers. This is the reason why FileExists is able to return true or false based on the path it receives.

Comment: Okay, nice to have all the information, as you can see from my questions there are several pitfalls

Comment: No problem.  So as the intranet security settings are correct, and FileExists works, why will the above script not remove what I want it to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I'm thinking the problem is with `$(this).parent().remove()` and your results, if you look at [this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/6uL8C/1/) versus [this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/6uL8C/2/), the first one doesnt work, but the second one works after we wrap it in a span, simply so the $results wont turn out empty.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hunch here, `FileExists` uses an AJAX call? In that case its asynchronous an will not return anything reliable since it exits the current flow of the application.

Comment: I've updated the original question to show the FileExists function.